# How do you do an IN query that has multiple columns in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a need to get columns for specific rows in the database, identified by more than one column. I'd like to do this in batches using an IN query.

In the single column case, it's easy:

```
SELECT id FROM foo WHERE a IN (1,2,3,4)
```

But I'm getting a syntax error when I try multi columns

```
SELECT id FROM foo WHERE (a,b) IN ((1,2), (3,4), (5,6))
```

Is there any way to do this? I can't just do two IN clauses because it potentially returns extra rows and also doesn't use the multi-column index as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Declan_K's idea:
To be able to use multi-column indexes and not having to update a separate column, you have to put the lookup values into a table which you can join:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE lookup(a, b);
INSERT INTO lookup VALUES ...;
CREATE INDEX lookup_a_b ON lookup(a, b);
SELECT id FROM foo JOIN lookup ON foo.a = lookup.a AND foo.b = lookup.b;
```

(The index is not really necessary; if you omit it, the SQLite query optimizer will be forced to look up the `lookup` records in the `foo` table, instead of doing it the other way around.)

If you want to avoid the temporary table, you could construct it dynamically using a subquery:

```
SELECT id
FROM foo
JOIN (SELECT 1 AS a, 2 AS b UNION ALL
      SELECT 3     , 4      UNION ALL
      SELECT 5     , 6               ) AS lookup
 ON foo.a = lookup.a
AND foo.b = lookup.b
```

This will still be able to use an index on `foo(a,b)`.

Comment: Larry Lustig's answer is also correct, but this seems to be the most thorough solution

Comment: This seems like a bit more work for no additional gain, but should give identical results. . .

Comment: Larry: I'm using the dynamically constructed subquery version in my code now and it works well. The reason I chose that one is because I'm not sure the query planner can compose the index scans across the 'union all' in your example, so I think it probably hits the index more often. I haven't yet verified that but if I have some time I may give it a shot and see.

Answer (score 2):

This command should use an index on (a, b):

```
 SELECT id FROM foo WHERE a = 1 and b = 2
 UNION ALL
 SELECT id FROM foo WHERE a = 3 and b = 4
 UNION ALL
 SELECT id FROM foo WHERE a = 5 and b = 6
```

It's tedious to write if you have a length list of pairs, but that can be automated.

Answer (score 1):

What I think you really want is another (string) column that contains the Key/Value pairs, so that you can query the combination specifically.  Something like:

```
SELECT id FROM foo WHERE c IN ('1,2', '3,4', '5,6')
```

You can populate the new column with something like:

```
UPDATE foo SET c = a||','||b
```

Comment: Bad, allows eq. 3,2 or 1,6

Answer (score -1):

You may need to convert a and b to strings but when that is done, concatenation will be the answer.

```
SELECT id FROM foo WHERE a||'_'||b IN ('1_2', '3_4', '5_6')
```

Comment: problem with this is its not going to use the index, which is the whole point. I may just go with an executemany and no IN clause for this case if no direct solution is available.

Comment: Alternative whould be to put the tuples you are searching for in a table (temp) and join on both columns with an INNER JOIN.

Comment: This solution requires a full tablescan, and assumes you'll be able to find a separator that is never found in either column. Both issues are deal killers.